# Pass envs into task.json on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm having problems passing my variables to my tasks in `task.json`.
I manage my env vars via [`direnv`](https://direnv.net/docs/installation.html) and an `.envrc`. Long story short, `direnv` automatically loads my env vars into the shell everytime I open it.

Now, the problem is that I feel like the shells between tasks aren't conserved.

Here is my task.json:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "func",
            "command": "host start",
            "problemMatcher": "$func-python-watch",
            "isBackground": true,
            "dependsOn": "pip install (functions)",
            "options": {
                "env": {
                    "SUBSCRIPTION_ID": "${env:SUBSCRIPTION_ID}",
                    "RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME": "${env:RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}",
                    "WORKSPACE_NAME": "${env:WORKSPACE_NAME}",
                    "TENANT_ID": "${env:TENANT_ID}",
                    "CLUSTER_ENDPOINT": "${env:CLUSTER_ENDPOINT}"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "set env",
            "type": "shell",
            "osx":{
                "command":  "direnv allow ."
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "pip install (functions)",
            "type": "shell",
            "dependsOn": "set env",
            "osx": {
                "command": "pip3 install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I know the envs exist because if I do a simple printenv in my terminal they appear, however not in the tasks shell.

Am I missing something?

Comment: what is the environment of the shell you use to start VSC, that is the environment that the task and launch config start with

Comment: if `${env:SUBSCRIPTION_ID}` exists, why redefine it with the same name in the task environment

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK All Tasks are executed in separate terminals and shells. They do not share environments. They can be run in parallel if `dependsOn` has more than one, also.
You will have to define environment in your `func` task. Aren't you missing `label` there too?

It looks like you are working on Azure Functions. If that's the case you should probably define your configuration variables in `local.settings.json` under `"Values"` instead, as this will mimic configuration on Azure.

I have not used `direnv` but can you not make it to always allow the `.envrc` file. Then env vars would be set before VSCode starts anything and they should be available then.

Environment can be defined in `.env` file too, see your folder or workspace settings in VSCode:

```
// Absolute path to a file containing environment variable definitions.
  "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
```